# ocsp validate certificate by passing certificate text instead of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, ocsp

I am trying to run my certificate against ocsp responder to check for validity.
I am using Ruby on rails but basically running this as a system command

Currently, the following command works and stores the results in a file.

```
command = "openssl ocsp -issuer #{Rails.root}/ca-cert.crt -cert #{Rails.root}/"+@filename+".crt -CAfile #{Rails.root}/ca-cert.crt -url "+CONFIG[:ocsp_responder] +" > " + outputfile"
system(command)
```

But instead of passing the "@filename.crt", I want to pass the public_certificate itself. What would be the appropriate syntax for that?

I tried the following:

```
 command = "openssl ocsp -issuer #{Rails.root}/cert/ca-cert.crt -cert #{cert} -CAfile #{Rails.root}/data/certs/ca-cert.crt -url "+CONFIG[:ocsp_responder] +" > " + outputfile
# cert = the certificate in text --BEGIN..blah blah.--END
```

This does not work. Is there an alternative without having to specify a public cert file?

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, i do not believe that the command line openssl client does in any form accept certificates as a string, assuming you want to do something like:
`cert = request.env['VAR_WITH_CERT]`

you probably will have to go through some temporary file.